# I have 2 columns of data that I need to compare. If the values in column 1 match I need to add their corresponding column 2 values

Tags: python

So I have a very large data set that looks like this.

```
1       1.05
1       0.95
1       1.00
2       1.02
2       1.03
3       .97
```

If the values in the first column match then I need to add their corresponding column 2 values. In the case all the 1s match so I would add (1.05 +.95 +1) = 3.
Then the 2s match, so it would go (1.02 + 1.03) = 2.05. And the 3 is fine. I need help writing a code to compare numbers and if the number in column 1 matches the number above or below it, add their corresponding column 2 values.

After all that is done I need it to plot the newfound values (3, 2.05, and .97 in this case).

I already have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt(fname='Project2-3.dat')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

energy = df[6]*1000

plt.hist(energy, bins=250)
plt.show()
```

But I don't know Python well enough to add the if command. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your data into a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). This will, amongst many many others, allow access to the groupby function. You can then group rows together that have the same index value (your first column). Then on each of those groups, you simply compute the `sum`.

Here is an example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: index_values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

In [3]: values = [1.05, 0.95, 1.00, 1.02, 1.03, 0.97]

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index_values)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
      0
1  1.05
1  0.95
1  1.00
2  1.02
2  1.03
3  0.97

In [6]: grouped = df.groupby(by=df.index).sum()

In [7]: grouped.plot()
Out[7]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fcb2a35db38>

In [8]: plt.show()
```

This then gives me:

[image: barplot of summed groups]

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do that along with an

    energy = df[6]*1000

command? The data set is massive and has to be loaded in. Imputing it in by hand wouldn't work.

Comment: I should point out, that this method takes all values from the index into a single group. If you require only consecutive values, then you could simply create a function that runs over all values in the index and creates a new column that repeats values for consecutive indices. Then use my method on this new column.

Comment: @Goku7144 - what do you mean? Are there missing values?